# Validating HTTP POST request body for a REST API

Tags: rest, api, http, post

We are thinking about different kind of validations for POST request body on server side.

Should we have a strict schema for POST request body and throw 4xx errors when user's request contains extra fields other than mentioned in the schema.

Also, I came across following while searching:

> More importantly, schema validation is generally not a good idea in a REST service.
>   A major goal of REST is to decouple client and server so that they can evolve separately.

Does the above means that user can send unnecessary data also in request body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would absolutely strictly validate any incoming data, if you can. Postel's law of 'being liberal in what you accept' is widely accepted as a bad idea.

A big issue is that a client might misspell an optional field and not get feedback on what they should have sent. There's rarely a good reason for a server to just accept garbage values, because generally it's a strong indicator of a bug existing somewhere. It's smart to want that bug to be very visible instead of it being silently ignored.

If you're building an API, use JSON-Schema and be strict.

Comment: .... and also widely accepted as a good one.    https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12401/be-liberal-in-what-you-accept-or-not?newreg=a977ab9cfcb84def96debc224e8ae448 is an interesting conversation, and this is really a dup of that.

Comment: @DanFarrell take a look at the wider internet community of protocol designers and you'll find that Postel's law is almost universally discouraged now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does to me.  There's no compelling reason to reject a request that you can respond to successfully, just because there's extra data, for reasonable cases (you'd have POST size limits on an API anyway).

The point about decoupled evolution is a good one.  Fields come and go; there's no reason not to honor requests made with an outdated definition of which fields are required.  I recommend against *adding* required fields to the same API endpoint for the same reason.  At the end of the day, *change* is the biggest factor of difficulty with APIs, and *rigidity* only makes the impact of that change more painful.  After all, don't we "just" want it to work for our users?

Comment: what will stop users from sending useless data in body. Shouldn't we stop them from doing that? Yes APIs evolve over time and thus request body may also completely change. But that's completely different. What I am thinking of is that I have a API body having required and optional fields. Should I throw some 4xx error if user is sending some other data other than "required and optional" fields

Comment: To summarize, no you don't want to stop them from doing that .  They've already made the request.  You've already paid for compute and network to receive it.  Ask yourself, what are you really gaining in rejecting the request?